Why does Immediate to Memory-Direct require the ModRM byte?
I wanted to look at the object code for certain instructions to understand them better. My understanding of the modRM byte is that it is useful for the register-to-register opcode 8A (8-bit) , as it is used to determine the destination and source registers/memory.
My intuition led me to believe that a modRM byte is not necessary for immediate to memory direct, as all you would need is the opcode, address of memory, and the hard coded value.
However when debugging Visual Studio:
mov x, 100 ; x is byte length

the object code is:
c6 05 xx xx xx xx 64

05 must be the modRM byte here.
My question is, what is its significance? Why is it necessary here?

The instruction supports all the usual addressing modes and thus needs a modr/m byte to encode the addressing mode used.  Additionally, the r field is used as a sub-opcode and must be zero.

In general the address may be [rsp - 32] or [rbp + 8] or [rax + 4 * rcx + 5] or whatever, sometimes also requiring a SIB byte. You couldn't do any of that if you only had an offset to work with.

Let's switch the rsp and rbp in my previous comment but you get the idea. Many addresses are not simply a constant, actually most aren't. Though, a mov instruction that uses only a constant for the memory address it not useless, and in fact we have the (small) family of MOV moffs, reg instructions, opcodes A2 and A3. Those don't have a ModRM byte.

It made the encoding more consistent... at least as far as "consistent" means for the x86, anyway.
The instruction needs to encode a memory address.  Rather than having a special byte encoding for instructions that don't involve a register, Intel decided with the 8086 to encode non-register instructions as ModR/M bytes with a dummy "reg" field.  This way, the same ModR/M decoding logic would be used for both register operations and non-register operations.  This choice has been retained all the way to modern x86-64.
When there is no register field, the "reg" field of the ModR/M byte is often used as a way to encode multiple operations as the same base opcode.  Example:
call rax  ; FF D0
jmp rax   ; FF E0

Here, the "reg" field is 2 for indirect call and 4 for indirect jmp.  In Intel and AMD manuals, this is denoted as FF /2 and FF /4 respectively: a ModR/M byte with "reg" of those particular values.

It's not a dummy register; it steals the register slot; so you have to do index that register as that register + 0; in 16 bits, the register is bp, the encoding of [bp] is actually [bp + 0] which is one byte larger. Since [bp + 0] is rare this works out.

My explanation can be further improved by adding the 32 and 64 bit register that is stolen.

@Joshua What is that supposed to mean? The reg/spare field can encode an additional opcode part. Whether to call this "stealing" is arguable but it certainly doesn't encode anything to do with the memory operand. The [bp] versus [bp + byte 0] question has absolutely nothing to do with the spare field.
